# Dividing variable values in php...not working

Tags: php, arrays

Anyone have any thoughts on why I am not getting any output here?

//my code

```
$numer = $times_positive['positive_occurrence'];
$denom = $times_tested['variable_occurrence'];
$percent_postive = $numer / $denom;
echo "it wins " . $percent_positive . " of the time.";
```

$numer & $denom are values of an array, what I believe to be integers.
when I echo them (in this example) $numer = 25 and $demon = 50.  When I divide them, i should get 0.5, but it's not outputting anything...

//my output:
it wins of the time

I've stared at this for hours...I know I am probably doing something super stupid here, but need a fresh set of eyes on this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is unlikely to help anyone in the future

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spot the difference:

```
$percent_postive = $numer / $denom;
            ^----
echo "it wins " . $percent_positive . " of the time.";
                              ^-----
```

See anything missing?

Comment: That's why you should turn on error reporting while debugging. It would generate an E_NOTICE level error.

Comment: ugh!  Thanks for the help!  Like I said, sometimes it just takes a second set of eyes.

Comment: @user2828701: as cmate pointed out, you should have error_reporting/display_errors turned on. Otherwise you're debugging in the dark with 2 arms and half an eyeball tied behind your back. They should never be off on a development system.